# How to Solve problem UIPickerView Fatal error: Index out of range [IOS Swift 5.1 Xcode 11.2]

Tags: ios, json, uipickerview, swift5, xcode11

I'm trying to Get the selected value of `UIPickerView` 
when running App. But I get error,

> Fatal error: Index out of range

I debug by `print("selected ==>\(selected)")` in  `numberOfRowsInComponent` function. I get value of `selected` by debugging as 0.

How to solve this problem?

```
Value From Postman
- Plandate function
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/ProjectService/PODService.svc/GetPlanDate/2
"[  {    \"PlanDate\": \"26/08/2019\",    \"PlanDateFullFormat\": \"20190826\"  },  {    \"PlanDate\": \"27/08/2019\",    \"PlanDateFullFormat\": \"20190827\"  }]"

- PlanShipment
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/ProjectService/PODService.svc/GetShipment/2/20190826
"[  {    \"Shipment\": \"4505023278\"  },  {    \"Shipment\": \"4505023279\"  }]"
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/ProjectService/PODService.svc/GetShipment/2/20190827
"[  {    \"Shipment\": \"4505023244\"  },  {    \"Shipment\": \"4505023274\"  }]"
```

```
Return Value From JSON
- Plandate function
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/ProjectService/PODService.svc/GetPlanDate/2
pplandateCategories ==>["20190826", "20190827"]

- PlanShipment
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/ProjectService/PODService.svc/GetShipment/2/20190827
getpShipmentDCPlanData ==>["4505023244", "4505023274"]
```

```
Swift
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
      return 2
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if component == 0 {
            return pPlandateCategories.count
        }else{
            let selected = pickerview.selectedRow(inComponent:0)
           return pShipmentCategories[selected].count ———>. Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if component == 0 {
            return pPlandateCategories[row]
        }else{
            let selected = pickerview.selectedRow(inComponent:0)
            return pShipmentCategories[selected][row]
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if component == 0{
            pickerview.reloadComponent(1)

        }else{
            let selected = pickerview.selectedRow(inComponent:0)
//            getpPlanDatePickerView.text = "PlanDate:" + " " + pplandateCategories[selected][row]
            someTextField.text = "Shipment:" + " " + pShipmentCategories[selected][row]
        }
    }
```

```
Error when Run Project 
My WebService ==> http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/ProjectService/PODService.svc/GetPlanDate/2GetPlanDate/2
Fatal error: Index out of range
2019-12-19 10:55:14.459056+0700 pickerDateAndShipment[782:19020] Fatal error: Index out of range
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crash can occur only if the data for the components is loaded asynchronously and the data source is empty at the moment the table view is reloaded the first time.

To avoid the crash check if the `pShipmentCategories` array is empty

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if component == 0 {
        return pPlandateCategories.count
    } else {
        let selected = pickerview.selectedRow(inComponent:0)
        return pShipmentCategories.isEmpty ? 0 : pShipmentCategories[selected].count
    }
}
```

Comment: I get more error Fatal error: Index out of range after debug in title arrow didSelectRow function `let selected = pickerview.selectedRow(inComponent:1) return pShipmentCategories.isEmpty ? 0 : pShipmentCategories[selected][row]` —> if use 0 Cannot convert return expression of type 'Int' to return type 'String?' And Fatal error: Index out of range

Comment: `didSelectRow` should work without any changes. Pancho's suggestion is wrong

Comment: Thank you for answer, didSelectRow. I writing correctly?
` func pickerView (_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
         if component == 0 {
             pickerview.reloadComponent (1)
         } else {
             let selected = pickerview.selectedRow (inComponent: 1)
             print ("selected didSelectRow ==> \ (selected)")
             someTextField.text = "Shipment:" + "" + pShipmentCategories [selected] [row] -> Fatal error: Index out of range
         }
     }`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, My App run normally not have an error